# KFP file in ubuntu?

Tags: printing, pdf, file-format, adobe-acrobat

My print shop provides a KFP file for checking a PDF for print readiness. It seems that this file can be imported into Acrobat Professional (keyword: Preflight Profile), but is a Kinko's File Prep Tool file. Is there any way of checking a PDF with a KFP file in ubuntu?